# Why isn't selectedindexchanged firing?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu, code-behind

I have the following DropDownList defined:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStuff" CssClass="myCssClass" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PopulateAnotherDropdown" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

However, my PopulateAnotherDropdown method isn't firing.  I have a breakpoint set on the method, and it's not being hit.

Here is my method write-up in code-behind:

```
public void PopulateAnotherDropdown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

For what it's worth, the page is rendering as follows:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlStuff" id="MainContent_ddlStuff" class="myCssClass">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you forget to add: `AutoPostBack="true"`

To fire the SelectedIndex of the dropdownlist control, it needs to postback to the server. For that to happen you to have to set `AutoPostBack="true"` in the control property.

Answer (score 2):

Please Set

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

of the dropdown.Because by default it is false except button control